# Changing Radio Select

Tags: html, css, timer, radio-button

Alright so I have a radio button slide show that I made with some simple CSS and HTML, but now I need it to change once every 3 seconds, but I still want it to be able to change by checking a radio button...

Here is my Css code

```
.photo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 1s;
    z-index: -1;
}

.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 800px;
    height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 10px;
    text-align: center;

}



input[type=radio]:checked ~ .photo {
    transition: all 1s;
        opacity: 100;
}

.photo1 {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    right: 52%;
}
.photo2 {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    right: 50%;

}
.photo3 {
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0;
    right: 48%;
}
```

and here is my html code

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<form class="container">
<table>
</tr>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="photo" class="photo1" checked="true">
<img src="Footloose.png" class="photo">
</td>

<td>
<input type="radio" name="photo" class="photo2" >
<img src="Shrek.jpg" class="photo">
</td>

<td>
<input type="radio" name="photo" class="photo3" >
<img src="LegallyBlond.jpg" class="photo">
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'm new to Java and Javascript, and when I tried, it didn't work. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: java and javascript are far apart from one another

Comment: Your question is not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try use setInterval() method, use the following code:

```
<script>
function setchecked(){
       var photos = document.getElementsByName("photo"),
                i = 0;
       for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
       {
            if(photos[i].checked == true)
            {
                photos[i].checked = false;
                i = i+1==3 ? 0 : i+1;
                photos[i].checked = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    setInterval(setchecked, 3000);
</script>
```